# extracting strings from an array of mixed data! (ruby)

Tags: ruby, multidimensional-array, split

given, for example, the following array of arrays..

```
mixed_data_1 = [
  ["The", 4, "quick"],
  [-1, "brown", "fox", 30],
  ["studied", 101, 233, "Ruby"]
]
```

how could one joing ONLY the strings within the array and leave out the integers. what I have so far is the following :

```
def join_nested_strings(aoa)
 new_array=[]
 counter1=0
  while counter1 < aoa.length do
   counter2=0 
    while counter2 < aoa[counter1].length do 
      if aoa[counter1][counter2].class == String
        phrase= aoa[counter1][counter2].join(' ') 
      new_array << phrase  
      counter2=counter2+1  
     end  
    end  
   counter1=counter1+1  
  end  
 new_array  
end
```

This isn't working - not sure how to use either .join, + , or maybe even .split to extract the strings and display them in a single array like this

```
["The quick brown fox studied Ruby"]
```

Any suggestions on help would be appreciated!

Comment: "This isn't working" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way:

```rb
[                 # Wrap the entire thing in an array.
  mixed_data_1.
    flatten.      # Recursively flatten the nested arrays.
    grep(String). # Filter out only strings.
    join(' ')     # Join the resulting strings together with a space.
]
```

However, when presented with such a problem, it is almost always better to fix the problem at the source and ensure that you don't get such "weird" data structures in the first place. Ruby is an object-oriented language, not an arrays-of-arrays-of-integers-or-strings-oriented language, one should generally manipulate rich, structured, "live" objects, not anemic, unstructured, "dead" data (or more precisely, those objects should manipulate *themselves*).

Comment: Sorry, but those links really have no relevance to this question other than that they are also manipulating data structures...

Comment: The whole point I am trying to make with this answer is that you *should not be manipulating data structures*, but instead model the problem domain with rich objects that *know how to manipulate themselves*. There is unfortunately not enough information in the question about the problem domain to give a relevant example for *this particular problem*, so instead I opted to give some examples of other cases where a seemingly complex "data structure manipulation problem" turns into a trivial object manipulation problem through proper domain modeling.

Answer (score 3):

One way:

```
sentence = mixed_data_1.flat_map do |items|
  items.select { |item| item.is_a?(String) }
end.join(" ")

[sentence]
# => ["The quick brown fox studied Ruby"]
```

Another, slightly simpler but less idiomatic way:

```
words = []
mixed_data_1.each do |items|
  items.each do |item|
    if item.is_a?(String)
      words << item
    end
  end
end

[words.join(" ")]
# => ["The quick brown fox studied Ruby"]
```

Note that instead of `.is_a?(String)` you could use `.class == String`, it's basically the same thing

Comment: @CarySwoveland eh? I always just use `==`.

Comment: "Note that instead of `.is_a?(String)` you could use `.class == String`, it's basically the same thing" – *Never* use `.class == whatever`. First off, it breaks when using inheritance. For example, if you use `.class == Integer`, it is almost guaranteed to break, since the Ruby Specification *explicitly* allows implementation-defined subclasses of `Integer`. And secondly, even *if* you want to ignore inheritance, there is the IMHO much more intention-revealing `instance_of?`.

Comment: Note that `items.select { |item| item.is_a?(String) }` is equivalent to `items.select { |item| String === item }` (or `items.select(&String.method(:===))`), and in turn `foo.select(&bar.method(:===))` is always equivalent to `foo.grep(bar)`, so the `flat_map` block can be simplified to `items.grep(String)`.